# Upload to Amazon S3 from public URL

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I would like to use the [AWS iOS SDK](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios) to upload an image directly from a public url to a S3 bucket.

My goal is to avoid downloading then uploading the image, which would be obviously slower.
I tried to naively pass the URL to `AWSS3TransferUtility.uploadFile` like so :

```
import AWSCore
import AWSS3

// ...

AWSS3TransferUtility.register(
    with: AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration!,
    transferUtilityConfiguration: AWSS3TransferUtilityConfiguration(),
    forKey: "foo"
)

let utility = AWSS3TransferUtility.s3TransferUtility(forKey: "foo")!
let imageURL = URL(string: "https://via.placeholder.com/150/")!

utility
    .uploadFile(
        imageURL,
        bucket: "<bucket name>",
        key: "bar.jpeg",
        contentType: "image/jpg",
        expression: nil,
        completionHandler: nil)
    .continueWith {
        if let error = $0.error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

But it seems to accept only url of local files and return the error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain error 4.)

Any idea if this is possible and how ?

Comment: S3 can't download that for you. You have to download it either to the memory or to the disk before uploading to S3.

Comment: Aw that's a shame, thank you for your comment

Comment: You could potentially write a simple Lambda function that your iOS client could send a source URL and target S3 key to and that Lambda function would stream the source file into S3 for you. Could be invoked directly or via API Gateway. Might help if what you're really trying to do is avoid the transmission of the source file through your iOS app and the mobile device it's running on.

Comment: Great idea, I'll give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod) idead I was able to do it using a Lambda (simplified here) :

```
const https = require('https');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(url, (resp) => {
      if(resp.statusCode > 200) {
          reject('The image could not be loaded (HTTP ' + resp.statusCode + ')');
      }
      
      resp.setEncoding('binary');
      let chunks = [];

      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk, 'binary'));
      });
      resp.on('end', () => {
        let binary = Buffer.concat(chunks);
        resolve(binary);
      });
      
    }).on("error", (err) => {
      console.log("Error: " + err.message);
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}


exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    const url = ...;
    const bucket = ...;
    const key = ...;

    const buffer = await loadImage(url);

    const destparams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
        Body: buffer,
        ContentType: "image"
    };
    await s3.putObject(destparams).promise();
    
    return "OK";
  } catch(error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

Calling a Lambda using [AWSLambda](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AWSLambda) is quite simple :

```
let lambda = AWSLambdaInvocationRequest()!
lambda.functionName = // Lambda name
lambda.invocationType = .requestResponse
let parameters: [String: Any] = [:] // Parameters to pass to the lambda
let payload = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) 
lambda.payload = payload

AWSLambda.default().invoke(lambda) { response, error in
    //...
}
```